# Why doesn’t Obi-Wan Kenobi use the Force more?

Tags: star-wars

When I first watched "Attack of the Clones" and "Revenge of the Sith", I thought that there are a number of situations where Obi-Wan Kenobi makes life difficult for himself by failing to use the Force (we'll excuse him in "Phantom Menace", since he is still an apprentice). Two that come to mind right now are:

- Fight against Jango Fett on Kamino. He just uses his lightsaber to deflect Fett's blaster shots, instead of using the Force to fling the blaster of Fett's hand, or straight up throwing him against a wall until he's knocked unconscious.
- Fight against Gen. Grievous after both have lost their lightsabers. Five minutes earlier, OWK had shown he has enough Force command to fling Grievous around a huge hangar like a doll, but now he insists on trying to punch an opponent made of metal with his bare hands.

Is there an in-universe reason for these decisions?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Why don't Jedi (or Sith) use the Force to snap their foes' necks?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45901/5184). Also related: [Why did Jedi in the prequel movies use the force offensively?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64300/5184). I swear there was another one even more related, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: Well, in *Clone Wars* (the 2003 series, not *The Clone Wars*) when Mace Windu lost his lightsaber on Dantooine, he tried punching opponents made of metal with his bare hands. It worked all right for him.

Comment: Look, it sounds easy to just “use the force”, but unless you’ve got a Jedi ghost whispering “use the force” right in your damn ear it’s actually really easy to just forget.

Comment: He ran out of magic points.

Comment: @DarthSatan funny you should mention that: [Why didn't the fighters use force pull/push in the generator complex?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19211/5184)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I'm not sure I'm going to buy that. OWK has been training literally his whole life to use the Force to his advantage. It's like being raised up to carry a calculator with you at all times and being taught techniques to use it as effectively as possible, and then, the day someone asks you to multiply two large numbers, your first reaction is to go find some paper and a pen.

Comment: More related: [Do Jedi hold back with their force powers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/25043/5184) (discusses that it's taxing on them) and [How was Grievous able to defeat Jedi?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64248/5184) (discusses the fact that Force Push doesn't solve everything)

Comment: @Koldito: well maybe the batteries on the calculator ran out.